# How to un-publish a Ready For Sale app from store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

Is there any way **unpublish/Remove from sale** my iPhone app from the App Store?
I can't seem to find the option on [itunesconnect.com](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**A word of advice: Read iTunes Connect Guide carefully about this point!**

You can remove an app from sales or you can delete it... But pay attention!
If you decide to remove an app from sales, you'll be able to put it back on sales but if you choose to delete it you won't be able to restore it because you can't reuse your SKU, Bundle ID or App Name.

**To remove your app from sales:**

1. Go to your App Summary Page.
2. Click on **Price and availability** button.
3. Deselect all the stores Availability regions and then save changes **or** select "**Remove from sale**".
   [image]

**To delete your app:**

1. Go to your App Summary Page.
2. Click on Delete Application button.

**Note:** You can't delete an app if it is ready for sale. First you need to remove your app from sales and then you can delete it.

Comment: If I will remove my application will I be able to add new application with the same bundle id? the problem I have is that I need to remove iPad support. application is published but there are no downloads

Answer (score 17):

Unpublish/Remove from Sale app from apple App Store:

1. Select your app in iTunes Connect.
2. Go to **Pricing and Availability** in the App Store and Information section
3. Click **Remove from Sale** under Availability
4. Click **Save**

The app will disappear from App Store and the status is set to **Developer Removed From Sale** in iTunes Connect.

**Sample/Example Screen**
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/1507806314/appstore/pricing
[image]

Comment: Most up to date solution in 2016.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your app in iTunes Connect, click "Rights and Pricing", then click the link "Or, you can select specific stores here" at the bottom of the page.

On the next page, deselect all stores and save.

Answer (score 2):

On the new App Store Connect:

1. Open your app details page in App Store Connect.
2. Click **Pricing and Availability**.
3. At the bottom you should see an app availability territory/regions list. Click **Deselect All**.
   List should now state `(0 of 175 countries or regions)`
4. Click **Save**.
5. You should receive an immediate email with the subject line "**Your app status is Developer Removed From Sale**".